# Get values from function Woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to get values from function Woocommerce. So I want the values display out of the function. Is there another simple solution to solve it?

```
WooCommerce.get('products?per_page=100', function(err, data, res) {

  var data = JSON.parse(res);

  var id = data[0]['id'];

});

console.log(id); // output is undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get` is async, meaning that its callback is called after everything has finished.

`id` is not available anymore as it's scoped to the `get` callback function.

To help you debug, you could try:

```
var id;   

WooCommerce.get('products?per_page=100', function(err, data, res) {
    var data = JSON.parse(res);

    // keep the data you want in another variable, or object.
    id = data[0]['id']; 

    console.log(id); // test inside the function
});
```

The callback gets called when a response is received from the server.

Comment: is there another simple to solve it without using callback function?

Comment: @IkramSyakir nope, as it's the nature of async programming in JavaScript.

Comment: if i'm using callback function, how do i execute the code?

Comment: @IkramSyakir added details to the answer